# Capacity of AWGN channel with infinite bandwidth

Tags: information-theory

I am supposed to find the capacity of an AWGN communication channel with infinite bandwidth $B$, signal power $S$ and spectral density of noise $n/2$.

Now, I know that the formula for calculating capacity is

$C = B * log2(1 + S/N)$,

where

$N = n/2 * 2B $,

but the infinite bandwidth is confusing me.

Comment: write $C$ as a function of $B$ and let $B \to \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capacity of a continuous-time AWGN channel with bandwith $B$ is ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_capacity#AWGN_channel)),

$$ C=B \log\left(1+\frac{S}{N_0 B}\right)$$

You just need to let $B\to \infty$ and compute the limit (note that there is an indeterminancy here to resolve, as the first factor tends to $\infty$ and the second to $0$).

Comment: but I still don't understand why when the SNR is low, $C$ is nearly insensible to bandwith when $B \to \infty$ ? (so that the limit $\lim_{B \to \infty} C \ne \infty$) is there an intuitive explanation of that ? my intuition  would be the opposite : that with a fixed SNR, when $B \to \infty$ then $C \to \infty$.

Comment: That is indeed an interesting property, not very easy to grasp intuitively. To begin with, you should understand that increasing $B$ (at fixed $S/N_0$) has two opposite effects: 1) it lets of transmit a more speed (Nyquist), hence increasing capacity (that's the first factor)  2) it injects more noise (hence decreasing capacity) (that's the second factor). For large $B$, the two effects compensate.